What Does the 'Cosɸ' Rating on a DC Relay Indicate?
I've purchased some DC relays from a manufacturer called "Leone".
The relays are marked with "50Hz Cosɸ 1":

I guess they want to imply a power factor rating?
But why would a relay that operates at DC have a power factor rating listed? The marking is on the output side, so is this possibly indicating something about the output? As far as I know, relays act essentially like mechanical switches, and mechanical switches typically don't mention "Cosɸ", so what's the relevance here?
[I wanted to check the datasheet for more details, but it requires an email and phone number for access, which currently isn't working either.]

It's not a rating for the coil, but for the contacts.
The same rules apply to relay contacts and mechanical switches. If you have a 10A relay, it does not mean you can drive any 10A load with it, as they may not be rated for it.
There might be a different rating for different loads.
The contacts are rated to handle loads that are purely resistive. And at 50 Hz it means the AC zero crossing of voltage or current will quench any arcing. So it might not be good for say 400 Hz mains like in some environments regarding aeroplanes.
It means the contacts are not rated to handle inductive loads, which may want to keep current flowing and will cause an arc in the contacts break.
It also means the contacts are not rated to handle capacitive loads, which may take a large inrush current spike when the contacts make.
At least the data on the relay does not mention much about the contact ratings, other than 10A 250VAC and 10A 28VDC.
It does not mean that you cannot use it for capacitive and inductive loads at all - it simply means don't expect 10A rating. But you don't get any data how much current it is OK to switch when PF isn't 1.

your comment on the 400 Hz switching rating got me thinking. Would that not be less stressful than switching at 50 Hz as the max time to zero-cross would be reduced to 1/8?

@Transistor It may depend on many things, but even if the zero crossings happen more often, is the voltage low enough for long enough for the arc to suppress so it does not keep triggering.

@Transistor The ionized air has a certain lifetime during which it remains conductive even without a current flowing. The ions within it need to recombine and cool down before it's an insulator again. At 400Hz, there's less time for that because the zero-crossing is quicker. This makes the arc harder to extinguish.

So what would it say if it could handle inductive loads?

@tuskiomi, it probably can - but derated. You'd need to check the datasheet. There isn't room to print the full specifications on the relay!

@tuskiomi Often they give a cos-phi rating of 0.4 and/or 0.7.

This means that the relay is only rated switch AC when the power factor is 1. In other words: It's rated to switch resistive loads, but not capacitive or inductive ones. You can for example switch a heater with that relay, but not a motor.
If you try anyway, the relay might burn up its contacts or fail to open due to arcing / contact welding. It might also just work if you're lucky, but there's no guarantees.

Does this mean it's unsuitable for switching even a basic AC load, like a simple capacitive dropper connected to a single LED that needs just a few milliamps, or a low current step-down transformer? As far as I know, very few modern loads are purely resistive. Most devices, from phone chargers to LED bulbs, don't have a PF of 1. Would using this relay require some sort of PFC to use this relay?

@15Volts It might be okay, it might not be. The manufacturer of the relay is making absolutely no guarantees about it. You'd have to try. Inrush current from the capacitive dropper might just weld the contacts immediately if you're unlucky, or it could be totally fine. You'll definitely know when that happens because the relay will be permanently stuck on.

@15Volts No PFC. Usually (not always, but often enough it gets the job done unless you work with something exotic) derating is good enough. So if you want to switch 10A of LEDs, you can't use the relay you found. You'd need something with a higher amperage rating. And the lifetime isn't going to be guaranteed either, it may fail twice as fast. Just because you're using a part out of spec, doesn't mean it won't work. There's just nothing guaranteed about the behaviour at that point. And when using the parts professionally, this could have certification issues. Test it. Rigorously.

@Mast: Since no load is ever going to be free of parasitic inductance or capacitance, any relay would need to tolerate some level of capacitive or inductive effects, at least with some form of derating.  If a load behaves as an RLC circuit with non-zero effective series resistance and non-infinite effective parallel resistance, I would think it would be possible to compute some value R such that the RLC circuit would never impose more stress than an ideal resistor R, and that it should be safe to use a relay that would be able to handle a straight resistive load R.
